Functors in $Grp$
Are they such functors $F:Grp\to Grp$, that $|F(G)|=n$ implies $|G|<f(n)$ for some $f$. Maybe it's known, what they're characterized with?
Thanks!

Interesting question, but you should add some context, and correct your 2 typos: "Are they" for "Are there" and "some $f$." for "some $f$?"

It is easy to write down functors with this property (for example $F(G) = G \times G$) and functors without this property (for example $F(G) = 1$). Arbitrary functors are just much too general to say much about. Can you ask a more specific question? Are there specific functors you're interested in? Do you have some application in mind?

I don't even understand the question.
